# How can i grab an element from a row on a datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a simple datatable that shows some JSON data, received from an API endpoint.

I added a column that will hold a button on each row of the table. This button, when hit, will fire an AJAX request with the value of `id` for that **specific** row.

This actual code works, but now, instead of only sending the value of `id`, i would also like to edit the table so that, when the button is hit, it will send the values of `id` and `item` for that row. Can someone give me some piece of advice on how to do that?

On another question, i've been told to use Data Attributes, but i don't really know how would i integrate this into my current code. Any advice is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.btnClick', function() {
    var statusVal = $(this).data("status");
    console.log(statusVal)

    callAJAX("/request_handler", {
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")
    }, parameters = {
      'orderid': statusVal
    }, 'post', function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }, null, null);

    return false;
  });

  let orderstable = $('#mytalbe').DataTable({
    "ajax": "/myview",
    "dataType": 'json',
    "dataSrc": '',
    "columns": [{
      "data": "item"
    }, {
      "data": "price"
    }, {
      "data": "id"
    },],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": [2],
      "searchable": false,
      "orderable": false,
      "render": function(data, type, full) {
        return '<button type="button" class="btnClick sellbtn" data-status="replace">Submit</button>'.replace("replace", data);
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `full` parameter of the DataTables `render` function to store the values of the current seleceted row. In this way:

```
return '<button type="button" class="btnClick sellbtn" data-status="' + btoa(JSON.stringify(full)) + '">Submit</button>';
```

In the above code, the `data-status` data attribute will contains the stringified version of the current object value in base64 by using [**`btoa()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa). In base64 because for some reason we cannot directly store the stringified version of the object in the button's data attribute.

Then, in the button's click event, you have to do:

1. Decode the stringified object by using [**`atob()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob).
2. Parse into object by using **`JSON.parse()`**.

Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnClick', function() {

  var statusVal = $(this).data("status");

  // Decode the stringified object.
  statusVal = atob(statusVal);

  // Parse into object.
  statusVal = JSON.parse(statusVal);

  // This object contains the data of the selected row through the button.
  console.log(statusVal);

  return false;
});
```

Then, when you click in the button you will see this:

[image]

So, now you can use this object to send in your **`callAJAX()`** function.

See in this example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.btnClick', function() {

    var statusVal = $(this).data("status");

    // Decode the stringified object.
    statusVal = atob(statusVal);

    // Parse into object.
    statusVal = JSON.parse(statusVal);

    // This object contains the data of the selected row through the button.
    console.log(statusVal);

    return false;
  });

  let dataSet = [{
      "id": 1,
      "item": "Item 1",
      "price": 223.22
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "item": "Item 2",
      "price": 243.22
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "item": "Item 3",
      "price": 143.43
    },
  ];
  let orderstable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "data": dataSet,
    "columns": [{
      "data": "item"
    }, {
      "data": "price"
    }, {
      "data": "id"
    }, ],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": [2],
      "searchable": false,
      "orderable": false,
      "render": function(data, type, full) {

        // Encode the stringified object into base64.
        return '<button type="button" class="btnClick sellbtn" data-status="' + btoa(JSON.stringify(full)) + '">Submit</button>';
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="myTable" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the later answer; this is by far the best solution i've ever found! Thanks for taking your time to help and explain what you did, it's simple and works flawlessly, i'm going to reward this answer with a bounty as soon as i can. Thanks again!